# Probability of being dealt a pair in poker

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

> If it is assumed that all poker hands are equally likely, what is the probability of being dealt pair?

**Here is what I did:**
First I choose $1$ out of $52$:  ${52 \choose 1}$ - First Card

Second I choose $1$ out of $3$ to make a pair - ${3 \choose 2}$

Last I choose $3$ out of $50$ remaining card - ${50 \choose 3}$

So probability is
$$
\frac{{52 \choose 1} \cdot {3 \choose 2} \cdot {50 \choose 3}}{{52 \choose 5}}
$$

This seems to be wrong? Am I missing something? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to count the number of *sets* of five cards that are a pair, not the number of *lists of five cards*.
So you don't just pick the first card in 52 ways.

Instead, how many ways are there to choose a pair? $13 \cdot \binom{4}{2}$.
And how many ways to pick three other ranks? $\binom{12}{3}$. Then you can choose the suit of those three other ranks in $4^3$ ways.

Comment: Thanks, Cant we choose pair like 13c1 for first card than for remaining 3c1...

Comment: @G.Lane I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: how many ways are there to choose a just a pair pair? 
First I choose 1 card in 13c1 ways Then I choose remaining pair in 3c1 ways ...Is it right?

Comment: @G.Lane A "pair pair"? Why 13c1? That is the way to choose a rank. Why 3c1?

Comment: @G.Lane  A pair refers to two cards of the same rank.  The $13$ ranks are 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, A.  The factor of $13$ represents the choice of rank, the factor $\binom{4}{2}$ represents the number of ways of choosing two of the four cards of that rank,.

Comment: @G.Lane: What you are trying can be achieved as $52\times \binom31 \div2$. First card can be any, $\binom31$ for choosing another card of same rank, and division by $2$ because the cards could have been selected in either order. But why go into a more complex way with pitfalls (as your attempt shows)